# Why is show all command not working in OS X?

Tags: git, macos, bash

I was following this [tutorial by macworld](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-show-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x-finder-3520878/), and it did not work, I still can not see hidden files, in particular git hidden folders/files - `.gitignore` and `.git`.  The commands are:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

Comment: Does [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/64428/118444) or [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/112073/118444) help?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `f` in `Finder`.  OS versions from Mavericks and before used the command:

`defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE`

OSX and Yosemite uses:

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE`

After doing so I held down the <kbd>option</kbd> + clicking `Finder` at the same time to prompt Relaunch of `Finder`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you followed has `YES`, not `TRUE`.

Comment: true works just as well.